# Castle Windsor Typed Factory, binding multiple generic constraints?

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

Note: Before I begin please note this worked perfectly before the definition of ICommandHandler was changed to include multiple generic constraints, with one constraint it works fine.

However, I do not seem to be getting multiple constraints passed into the "arguments" array of the selector. Am I missing something?

This is called with:

```
   var handler = _factory.GetHandlerForCommand<TCommand, TResult>(command);
```

The Factory interface:

```
    public interface ICommandHandlerFactory
    {
        ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult> GetHandlerForCommand<TCommand, TResult>(ICommand command) 
            where TCommand : class, ICommand 
            where TResult : IDTOBase;
    }
```

The Selector class:

```
    public class HandlerSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector 
    {
        protected override Func<Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal, Castle.MicroKernel.IReleasePolicy, object> BuildFactoryComponent(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, string componentName, Type componentType, System.Collections.IDictionary additionalArguments)
        {
            return new HandlerResolver(componentName,
                                                    componentType,
                                                    additionalArguments,
                                                    FallbackToResolveByTypeIfNameNotFound,
                                                    GetType()).Resolve;
        }

        protected override string GetComponentName(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
        {
            return null;
        }

        protected override Type GetComponentType(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
        {
            var message = arguments[0];
            var handlerType = typeof (ICommandHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(message.GetType());
            return handlerType;
        }
    }
```

The Windsor installer file:

```
           container
                .Register(
                    Component
                        .For<HandlerSelector>()
                        .ImplementedBy<HandlerSelector>(),
                    AllTypes
                        .FromAssemblyContaining<ICommandHandlerFactory>()
                            .BasedOn(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>))
                            .WithService.Base()
                            .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.PerWebRequest)),
                    Component
                        .For<ICommandHandlerFactory>()


                .AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith<HandlerSelector>()));
```

Comment: Could you please add your `HandlerResolver` to your question? I'm having a similar issue with something and it would be interesting to see the guts of your HandlerResolver

Comment: @danrichardson did you find the HandlerResolver?? I've got the same problem. I will appreciate if you help me

Comment: I cannot remember, sorry. As per the answer though, I think it's more of a programming error rather than an issue within castle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case, writing the problem in a coherent manner often leads to an answer.

Changing the selector code to:

```
var genericArgs = method.GetGenericArguments();
var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(genericArgs[0], genericArgs[1]);
return handlerType;
```

Solves the issue.